# Чем известна Шамаханская царица?

Tags: литература

В сказке про Конька-Горбунка один из персонажей - это Шамаханская царица.
А вот интересно, почему ее Ершов вообще упомянул? Это вымышленный персонаж или какая-то конкретная историческая личность? И, если да, то чем она известна в истории и почему вошла в сказку?

Answer (score 1):

Вымышленный-то вымышленный, но указание на историческое лицо имеется. Ахматова увязала с Шемахой, но есть ещё такая версия, что это намёк на жену Ивана Грозного. Однажды делегация из Кабарды прибыла ко двору Ивана IV с богатыми дарами и с целым табуном великолепных кабардинских коней. Кабардинские мурзы (князья) просили царя принять их самих и их народ в российское подданство. Русские бояре, в свою очередь, тоже обратились к государю с просьбой закрепить союз с кавказскими народами царской женитьбой на одной из знатных кабардинок. И поехали государевы гонцы в Шемаху, и в Дербент, и в другие местности Северного Кавказа в поисках подходящей невесты для царя Московского и Всея Руси к тамошним властителям - шамхалам. Как видите, понятия Шемаха, шамхал чрезвычайно близки по звучанию к пушкинской Шамаханской царице.

Царская невеста нашлась среди дочерей мурзы черкасов горских Темрюка Юнгича. Черкасами на Руси именовались выходцы из Кабарды. Позднее многие из них по свойству с новой царицей получат имя князей Черкасских, оставивших заметный след в русской истории.

Кученей Темрюковна сделалась Марией Черкасской и была обвенчана с царем Иваном Грозным.

Царица изумила бояр не только своей красотой, но и необычным поведением. Облачившись в черкеску, легко вскакивала в седло и вместе с венценосным супругом отправлялась на царские охоты. Русская царица Мария умерла на 28-м году жизни, простудившись во время поездки с мужем по северным районам России. Летописец высказывает иную причину: царица была отравлена. С отравителями Иван Грозный жестоко расправился. Когда через год после смерти любимой жены Ивана IV Анастасии в Москву привезена была новая невеста, на этот раз даже другой веры — молодая «босурманка, купавна татарская», в народе возникло множество всевозможных предположений и домыслов. Говорили, что царь Иван Васильевич потому так быстро забыл свою некогда горячо любимую супругу, что его околдовала и очаровала своей невиданной красотой Мария. И опричнину увязывают с ней.

Ныне гробница царицы Марии находится в Архангельском соборе Московского Кремля. В центре города Нальчика ей поставлен памятник с надписью на постаменте: "Навеки с Россией".

Answer (score 0):

> Это вымышленный персонаж или какая-то
> конкретная историческая личность?

Вымышленный. Только вот **Ершовым** ли вымышлен? В 1834 году (в год написания "Конька-Горбунка") этот образ был использован ведь и другими авторами…

> Во время последнего приезда в Болдино
> Пушкин закончил «Сказку о золотом
> петушке». В статьях М. К. Азадовского,
> М. А. Шнеерсон, И. М. Колесницкой, В.
> Непомнящего и других, посвященных этой
> «Сказке», нет объяснений, почему
> Пушкин нарек царицу Шамаханской,
> откуда возникло это наименование и чем
> оно привлекло творческое воображение
> поэта.
>
> Исходя из звуковой ассоциации, А. А.
> Ахматова увязала имя восточной
> красавицы с селением Шамаха,
> славившимся далеко за пределами
> Азербайджана производством шелка.
> Шамаха была присоединена к России в
> 1820 г…
>
> В то время об этом отдаленном
> восточном селении можно было прочитать
> следующее: «Старая Шемаха,
> представляющая ныне почти одни
> развалины, была некогда цветущим и
> значительным торговым городом.
> Построения ее относят к самой
> отдаленной древности. Вольтер в
> истории Петра Великого утверждал, что
> она одно время была столицей царства
> Мидийского <...> Таламанский шелк
> <...> и по сию пору известен у нас под
> именем шамаханского»…
>
> В начале 1834 г. **Катенин**
> опубликовал поэму-сказку, написанную
> октавами, — «Княжна Милуша»…  Во
> второй песни «Княжны Милуши» Всеслав
> случайно вступает в боевой спор за
> владение землей, «той славной
> Шамаханской», которая известна на Руси
> «по дорогим шелкам»… На поле боя
> Зюльфира с открытым лицом обращается к
> Всеславу:
> *Я Шамахи законная царица…*
>
> Отталкиваясь от образа, нарисованного
> Катениным, а точнее, сохраняя лишь
> имя, **Пушкин** предложил читателю
> свой образ Шамаханской царицы…
>
> http://feb-web.ru/feb/pushkin/serial/v79/v79-120-.htm